# how to receive snmpv3 trap with AdventNet

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I'm trying to add the option to get a TRAP V3 (I can get TRAP V1 and V2).

here is the Session init

```
public void CreateSession()
{
    logger.debug(".in");        
    System.out.println("Waiting to receive traps .......");

    api = new SnmpAPI();
    api.setDebug( true );
    session = new SnmpSession(api);
    session.addSnmpClient(this);
    udpOpt = new UDPProtocolOptions();
    udpOpt.setLocalPort(TRAP_PORT);
    session.setProtocolOptions(udpOpt);
    try
    {
        session.open();
        String message="Succes to bind port: "+session.getLocalPort();
        logger.info(message);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String message = "Failed to open session - Port in use or permission denied. \n Message-  "+ ex.getMessage() + "\n Will exit from Trap process. ";
        logger.error(message, ex);
        System.err.println(message);
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }   
}
```

Every time I set up a device in V3 I perform the discovery and its registration to the tables using the method USMUtils.[init_v3_parameters](https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/javadocs/com/adventnet/snmp/snmp2/usm/USMUtils.html#init_v3_parameters(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.ProtocolOptions,%20com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpSession,%20boolean)).

```
 private void initV3Parameters(NEData neData) throws InterruptedException
{
    logger.debug("in.");
    try
    {
        UDPProtocolOptions udpOptions = new UDPProtocolOptions();
        udpOptions.setLocalPort(TRAP_PORT);
        udpOptions.setRemoteHost(neData.m_szIpAddress);
         USMUtils.init_v3_parameters(
                neData.usmUser,
                null,
                Integer.valueOf(neData.authProtocol),
                neData.authPassword,
                neData.privPassword,
                udpOptions,
                session,
                false,
                Integer.valueOf(neData.privProtocol));
        printToLog("success",neData);
    }
    catch (SnmpException exp) {
        logger.error(exp.getMessage()+" for ip = "+neData.m_szIpAddress,exp);
        discoveredDeque.put(neData);
        printToLog("failed",neData);
    }


}
```

When TRAP V1 or V2 arrives it comes to this function and it works perfect.**But I want to add the V3 as well**

```
/**
 * Receives incoming PDUs and adds them to the traps queue. Notifies the
 * internal thread on the arrival of each PDU.
 */
public boolean callback (SnmpSession session, SnmpPDU pdu, int requestID)
{
    logger.info("in session= "+session+" ,pdu= "+pdu+" ,requestID = "+requestID);
    if (pdu == null)
    {
        logger.info("Received null PDU");
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the PDU to the end of the traps queue.
        // Notify the internal thread.
        try
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                Object t = m_Traps.addElement(pdu);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    // The new trap replaced an old one.
                    logger.info("Queue full: replaced old PDU");
                }
                notify();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
        }
    }
    // All PDUs are handled, so true should always be returned.
    return true;
}
```

I have `debugPrint` implementation from `SnmpClient` and it seems that AdventNet gets the TRAP but does not do anything with it...

The SNMP agent is implemented using NetSNMP.

What is missing to make AdventNet handle the V3 TRAP?

Is this the right callback function to use?

`public boolean callback (SnmpSession session, SnmpPDU pdu, int requestID)`